# Elisp code to bind a keychord to another keychord

Tags: emacs, elisp

In Emacs, with the idea of binding a keychord to another keychord, why is this elisp code not working?

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") (kbd "C-s"))
```

(The idea being, in this example, to get "C-f" to do the same as "C-s".)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it not work either, but the usual way to achieve your purpose is just binding a key to a interactive command, instead of a string or keyboard macro, in this case `(kbd "C-s")`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") #'isearch-forward)
```

or (the above is better)

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") (key-binding (kbd "C-s")))
```

Comment: What's the function of the # ?

Comment: `#'` is used to quote the `isearch-forward)` functioin, so `#'isearch-forward` becomes `(function isearch-forward)`, symbol quote `'` works here as well, though `#'` provides more information. Emacs Lisp info manual has some info on this http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, I was expecting the following to be true: What you are attempting doesn't work, because you're binding the result of `(kbd "C-s")` to a key, which is an internal Emacs key representation and not the function that is (globally) set to the key. However, as xuchunyang pointed out, that's not entirely correct. `global-set-key` calls `define-key` internally which has in its documentation the following part:

> (define-key KEYMAP KEY DEF)
>
> In KEYMAP, define key sequence KEY as DEF. KEYMAP is a keymap.
>
> KEY is a string or a vector of symbols and characters, representing a
>   sequence of keystrokes and events. [...] 
>   DEF is anything that can be a key's definition:
>   nil (means key is undefined in this keymap),
>   a command (a Lisp function suitable for interactive calling),
>   a string (treated as a keyboard macro), [...]

And indeed, xunchunyang's example `(global-set-key [?l] (kbd "C-f")` works as you expect. `(global-set-key [?l] (kbd "C-s")` doesn't work, because `isearch-forward` expects an argument (the search regexp) which `interactive` will ask for. Only if you provide one, this particular keyboard macro will work, i.e. `(global-set-key [?l] (concat (kbd "C-s") "foo"))` will bind a search for "foo" to the key "l".

xuchunyang's answer is absolutely right: the best way is to name the function explicitly via `(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") #'isearch-forward)`. 
You can easily figure out the function that is bound to a key by typing `C-h k` and then the key which you want to "copy": e.g. `C-h k C-s`) will show you that `C-s` is (usually, cf. below) bound to `isearch-forward`.

The approach using `key-binding` could, in the general case, lead to strange results: depending on where and how you execute this (i.e. interactively in some buffer or in your .emacs), results may differ, because `key-binding` honours current keymaps, which might assign different functions to keys.

Comment: `(kbd "C-s")` here can be thought as a keyboard macro which can be consider as a command as well (according to http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keyboard-Macros.html), for example, `(global-set-key [?l] [?\C-f])` will let `l` to do the same as `C-f`, it works as expected, but I don't know why OP's example doesn't work.

Comment: `global-set-key` calls `define-key` finally, which, as you say, treats any given string as a keyboard macro. Given that `kbd` returns a string, I agree that this should work, so I stand corrected. The documentation of `global-set-key` is quite misleading.